# Can haproxy group backends per ip range?

Tags: haproxy

Scenario:
I have two groups of backend servers. And then I set weight 1 to group A, and set weight 2 to group B. The backends in group A are located at 172.16.11.XXX, the backends in group B are located at 172.16.12.XXX.

Question: 
I don't find a wildcard for specifying the backends in haproxy documentation.

And I don't want add another haproxy layer in the middle of frontend and backends. Any suggestion ids appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can create happroxy backend and putt all A group server in 1 backend and group B will be backend 2 after that create master upstream and put both backend and give priority weight 1 , weight 2